# Height CSS Percent Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust the height of a picture by a percentage, rather than a pixel.  However, when I use `height: 30%;` it doesn't work, but `height: 30px;` does work.  What am I doing wrong?

My snippet is mind boggingly easy.

```css
.imagebanner {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Welding-banner.jpg" alt="welding-banner" class="imagebanner" />
```

Comment: Try `height:30vh` (vh=viewport height)

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s Still nothing, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a percentage value for `height`, the parent element needs to have a defined height (for example 100%), and this goes up to the body and html, so as a start you can begin with adding

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

and also give height definitions to all the elements *in between* `body` and your image.

Answer (score 0):

Update your browser and then try. Sometimes if you're using old browser. New features of HTML don't work in old browser.

Comment: Its not a browser issue, not browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a 100% height on the parent element.

```css
.imagebanner {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://christiancomputerrepair.com/wp-content/themes/christiancomputerrepair/images/home_computer.png" class="imagebanner">
</div>
```